# Select attachment from list and send using php mail

Tags: php, email

all im trying to make this form work but having some issues, here is part of my sender script

```
       $mail->AddAttachment($_POST[file];);      // attachment
```

i have a form that simply posts the valuse from a selection on the list and comes to my sender script how would i ask it to find the file name file1 and add it to the email as an attachment ?, so i can select file2 from the list iot attaches file 2 file 3 picked same principle.

any ideas

Comment: I suppose that you do not have semicolon after `$_POST[file]` as you have posted in question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're trying to accomplish a multiple file select and attach them to you email. You have to use arrays. Name your file input name as

```
<input name="attachment[]" type="file" multiple="true">
```

Then use foreach loop

```
foreach ($attachment['error'] as $key => $error) {
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
           // Your code goes here.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the files were uploaded in the POST request then you should use $_FILES instead of $_POST. (Be sure your file upload form has attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` otherwise the file upload will not work.)

See: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

If you uploaded many files in the request, you can get them by using variables: `$_FILES['file1']`, `$_FILES['file2']`, ...

If you need to attach uploaded file in email you should use tmp_name of the file (it is temp localization on your server where file is), so you get:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name']);
```

Also you can check if files were uploaded successfully. The value of `$_FILES['file1']['error']` should be 0. If is not then see here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php